# Capistrano keeps asking me for ssh password on deploy to production (with Github action)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, deployment, github-actions, capistrano

I use Capistrano to deploy my Rails app to my private server which I have access to throught VPN + SSH. I implemented a GitHUb action to have continuous deployment.
I can connect to the server via SSH after setting the VPN.
But Capistrano is still asking for the credentials.

I started the ssh agent + added the private key to it, on the ssh session of the github action on the server.

I tried

- locally on my computer, that works but even when I ssh myself
- on the server and try to deploy `cap production deploy` from it to it, it still ask me for the password.
- i tried adding a config file on the server

The ssh key is added as a secret to the repo and works as the Github action can ssh to the server. But somehow Capistrano still ask for the passowrd.
Is it a forward agent thing? I set the option on the `deploy.rb` as

```
set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true}
```

```
name: Deploy to Server
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
jobs:
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
      REPO_URL: "git@github.com:${GITHUB_REPOSITORY}.git"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Set up Ruby
        uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          # runs 'bundle install' and caches installed gems automatically
          bundler-cache: true
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: |
          gem install bundler
          bundle install
      - name: Install OpenVPN
        run: |
          sudo apt update 
          sudo apt install -y openvpn openvpn-systemd-resolved
          echo "${{ secrets.VPN_USERNAME }}" >> auth.txt
          echo "${{ secrets.VPN_PASSWORD }}" >> auth.txt
          echo "${{ secrets.VPN_CONFIG }}" >> priicer.ovpn
          chmod 600 priicer.ovpn
      - name: Connect to VPN
        run: |
          timeout 2m sudo openvpn --config priicer.ovpn --auth-user-pass auth.txt --verb 3 &
      - name: Wait for a VPN connection
        run: |
          for i in {1..10}; do
            if ping -c 1 ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}; then
              echo "VPN is set up"
              exit 0  # Exit loop with success status
            else
              echo "VPN is not yet ready. Retrying in 10 seconds..."
              sleep 10
            fi
          done
          echo "VPN setup not confirmed after multiple attempts."
          exit 1  # Exit loop with failure status
      - name: Set up SSH and deploy
        uses: fifsky/ssh-action@master        
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          user: deploy
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY}}
          args: "-tt"
          command: |
            cd ./priicer/current
            echo $REPO_URL
            echo -e "lock '~> 3.17.1'\n\nset :application, 'priicer'\nset :repo_url, $REPO_URL\nset :deploy_to, \"/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}\"\n set :ssh_options, { :forward_agent => true }" > config/deploy.rb
            BUNDLE_PATH="/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims/bundle" 
            echo "BUNDLE_PATH: $BUNDLE_PATH"  # Print the value of the BUNDLE_PATH variable
            eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"  # Start the SSH agent
            ssh-add ~/.ssh/github # Or whatever key you choose
            $BUNDLE_PATH exec cap production deploy
        # ./restart.sh
      - name: Kill VPN connection
        if: always()
        run: |
          sudo killall openvpn
```

Comment: Are you sure it's asking for an ssh password and not the password that protects the SSH key (SSH key passphrase)?

Comment: yes, when testing the deploy directly on the server, i can deploy by giving the same ssh password i used to connect to the server and the GitHub logs show:
deploy@***'s password:
deploy@***'s password:
deploy@***'s password:

Also for the ssh key pair i created for github/server i did not set a passphrase